# Jenkins Pipeline job with "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: windows, jenkins, jvm, heap-memory, heap-size

At the launch of the **job Jenkins Pipeline**,I get a Java heap space issue as shown in the screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oFHU.png)

As u can see in the screen shot , i'm using ansible to connect to windows ( success )
I've done some research and i found that i can fix this error by adding a parameter to dedicate memory to the **build process** which is possible only in a Freestyle Or Maven Job and i can't use those jobs because i'm adding a jenkins a file to my **pipeline job** as shown in the screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6jKX.png)
So How Can I solve this error in a Pipeline Job please ?
[pipeline job screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgJGr.png)

Thank u

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.